# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors

Tags: android, data-binding, android-library, android-proguard, aar

I'd like to build obfuscated AAR library which makes use of Android data binding. When I use the library with **minifyEnabled** **false** my library build successfully and my testing app works , after enabling ProGuard the  testing app doesn't compile since BR fields in the generated data binding classes can't be found.

Error:  Cannot resolve type for vm

```
    In layout :: 
        <data>
          <variable
                name="vm"
                type="com.XXX.ViewModel"/>
        </data>
```

Answer (score 2):

add this lines Inside your `Proguard` file.

```
-dontwarn android.databinding.**
-keep class android.databinding.** { *; }
-keep class android.databinding.annotationprocessor.** { *; }
```

[source here](https://github.com/ittianyu/POCenter/blob/master/app/proguard-rules.pro#L23)

It Works for me.

Comment: I have already added above lines in my proguard:-keep public class **.BR { public *; }
-keep public class **.BR$* { public *; }
-keepclassmembers class **.BR$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
-keep class android.databinding.** { *; }
-keepattributes javax.annotation.processing.*

-keep class * extends android.databinding.** { *; }
-keep class com.pnb.aeps.sdk.databinding.** {
   public  <fields>;
   public  <methods>;
}

Comment: @user3337017  add this `keep class com.pnb.aeps.sdk.scanner.RowScanMachineViewModel`